# Density plot looks normal, qqplot not normal Shapiro significative

Tags: normal-distribution

The following QQ plot looks with too many points out of the line, the density plot looks normal and the Shapiro Test p-value < 2.2e-16, so this is not a normal distribution but I've read not to trust Shapiro Test when I have about 1000 data points so I should conclude that this distribution is normal?[image]

[image]

Comment: Clear asymmetry suggests something is up. A) Did you calculate the skewness? A nominal rule-of-thumb is if Pearson Skewness $\ge$ 0.1, then you have to take corrective action, e.g., performing statistics on the log() of your measurements, rather thanon the measurements direclty. Also, are there additional factors (meta data, etc.) that you can use to subselect your data? This may also be a mixture of models, so you might have two or 3 normal distributions all sitting close together, but the  second and third are small enough so as not to create an obviously multimodal histogram.

Comment: @Peter Where does that rule of thumb come from?  It's not generally applicable, so it would be of interest to know its limitations and assumptions.

Comment: @PeterLeopold "Pearson skewness" is not uniquely defined. Pearson himself put most emphasis on measuring skewness relative to the mode, which had a major role in his system of distributions. But he did also use a dimensionless ratio based on third and second moments around the mean. And yet again (mean $-$ median) / SD appears in his work. But regardless I wouldn't regard skewness of about 0.1 on any measure I've encountered as requiring transformation. I would always want to see the data, however.

Comment: @Peter The problem here is more about kurtosis than skewness and it's not clear that taking the log is justified, even if it were skew. It depends on what the OP is going to use the data for.

Comment: I would not trust a scale for happiness [NB] with such results!

Comment: 1. I'd use $(mean-median)/s$, (Pearson's first skewness) and expect a positive number since the histogram is clearly (to my eye) asymmetric and skewed high. 2. The rule of thumb comes from a statistics in health sciences text I picked up a few years ago. It is just what they teach nurses. Not a panacea, but sometimes it works. Won't defend it; might use it! 3. I can't see any kurtosis by eye, but maybe you can. 4. The right thing to do? I can think of a few fancy things with priors, but something tells me the OP doesn't want to hear that. This is just a comment, not a sol'n, after all . . .

Comment: Non-normal Kurtosis can be hard to read off a density plot but is systematic and evident on the quantile plot, on which the tails diverge increasingly from the normal reference line.

Answer (score 2):

First, the density plot does not really look normal. It's symmetric, but the shape is wrong. I suggest generating a normal distribution with the same mean and variance as yours and then overlaying that density on the one you've got.  I am fairly sure you will see a mismatch.

Second, a quantile normal plot is often a better clue to nonnormality.

Third, and probably most importantly, why are you concerned about the normality of this variable? What are you going to do with the variable?

Comment: Thanks for all comments and answers, @Peter Flom I've got measures of "Happyness" for two groups of people, I plotted them against time and looks like one group gets higher values so I'm trying to statistically compare them, I run Shapiro test for both groups and got p value << 0.05 so I don't know if a t-test or Wilcoxon

Comment: I'd go with Wilcoxon.  Or maybe a bootstrap.

Comment: Ah, two distributions! Thanks for confirming what the data was hinting strongly at.

Comment: Thanks! so I'll go with Wilcoxon too :)  the main reason is because the Shapiro test << 0.05?